# Convert access log strings to array

Tags: php, regex, nginx, split, explode

Brilliant minds, please help me split this string. I would like to convert this to array using preg_split but i couldn't get the right regex.

```
time:27/Mar/2015:17:56:12 +0900 host:210.210.210.210    user:-  forwardedfor:-  req:-   method:-    uri:-   protocol:-  status:200  size:0  reqsize:0   referer:-ua:-   vhost:www.web.com   reqtime:59.992  cache:- apptime:-   https:  session_id:
```

Requirement:

```
array(
    'time' => '27/Mar/2015:17:56:12 +0900',
    'host' => '210.210.210.210',
    'user' => '-',
    'forwardedfor' => '-',
    'req' => '-',
    'method' => '-',
    'uri' => '-',
    'protocol' => '-',
    'status' => '200',
    'size' => '0',
    'reqsize' => '0',
    'referer' => '-',
    'ua' => '-',
    'vhost' => 'www.web.com',
    'reqtime' => '59.992',
    'cache' => '-',
    'apptime' => '-',
    'https' => '',
    'session_id' => ''
)
```

Actually this is from the access log of nginx. I would like to properly format the strings so i could display it in a table and so it would be easier to read.

Comment: Can you tell that after each name and value there will be an white space in the string?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I tried to execute this print_r(preg_split('/ {2,}/', "time:27/Mar/2015:17:56:12 +0900 host:210.210.210.210    user:-  forwardedfor:-  req:-   method:-    uri:-   protocol:-  status:200  size:0  reqsize:0   referer:-ua:-   vhost:www.web.com   reqtime:59.992  cache:- apptime:-   https:  session_id: ")); in http://writecodeonline.com/php/, but the result is not right.

Comment: explode will be a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
\s*time:(.*?)\s*host:([\d\.]{0,15})\s*user:(.*?)\s*forwardedfor:(.*?)\s*req:(.*?)\s*method:(.*?)\s*uri:(.*?)\s*protocol:(.*?)\s*status:(\d*)\s*size:(\d*)\s*reqsize:(\d*)\s*referer:(.*?)\s*ua:(.*?)\s*vhost:(.*?)\s*reqtime:([\d\.]*)\s*cache:(.*?)\s*apptime:(.*?)\s*https:(.*?)\s*session_id:(.*?)\s*
```

and extract each group accordingly.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/jK7rC2/1

```
$regex = "\s*time:(.*?)\s*host:([\d\.]{0,15})\s*user:(.*?)\s*forwardedfor:(.*?)\s*req:(.*?)\s*method:(.*?)\s*uri:(.*?)\s*protocol:(.*?)\s*status:(\d*)\s*size:(\d*)\s*reqsize:(\d*)\s*referer:(.*?)\s*ua:(.*?)\s*vhost:(.*?)\s*reqtime:([\d\.]*)\s*cache:(.*?)\s*apptime:(.*?)\s*https:(.*?)\s*session_id:(.*?)\s*";
if (preg_match_all($regex, $input_string, $matches_out)) {
   $_time = $matches_out[1];
   $_host = $matches_out[2];
   $_user = $matches_out[3];
   .....
}
```

More info on groups: http://regexone.com/cheatsheet